# Enabling stereoscopic view in OpenGL in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, stereo-3d

I want to use stereoscopic 3D in a C++ Qt application in an `QOpenGLWidget`.
The code I currently have is:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
//format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::StereoBuffers, true);
format.setStereo(true);
setFormat(format);
```

But that code is causing a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` as soon as I try to display the Window.

I have tried with both `setStereo` and `setOption` as you can see above, but both crash.

How could I know if stereoscopic 3D is supported to avoid calling those lines when it is not?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [a rather simple OpenGL program](https://github.com/g-pechorin/simple-quad) to test "can I use stereo on this computer" it should be easy to build/run with CMake and Visual Studio

It doesn't use Qt, but it will tell you if OpenGL Stereo really-really-works at the moment

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try